# Loop substrings to new column

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dataset that looks somewhat like this (using **python** and **pandas**):

```
           date                         text
0   Jul 31 2020    Sentence Numero Uno #cool
1   Jul 31 2020              Second sentence
2   Jul 31 2020      Test sentence 3 #thanks
```

So I use this bit of code I found online to remove the Hashtags like `#cool` `#thanks` as well as make everything lowercase.

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]) :
    df['text'][i] = ' '.join(re.sub("(#[A-Za-z0-9]+)", " ", df['text'][i]).split()).lower()
```

That works, however I now don't want to delete the hashtags completely but save them in a extra column like this:

```
           date                   text    hashtags
0   Jul 31 2020    sentence numero uno       #cool
1   Jul 31 2020        second sentence    
2   Jul 31 2020        test sentence 3     #thanks
```

Can anyone help me with that? How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: As some strings contain multiple hashtags it should be stored in the hashtag column as a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way to go about this would be the following:

```
df['hashtag'] = ''
for i in range(len(df)) :
    df['hashtag'][i] = ' '.join(re.findall("(#[A-Za-z0-9]+)", df['text'][i]))
    df['text'][i] = ' '.join(re.sub("(#[A-Za-z0-9]+)", " ", df['text'][i]).split()).lower()
```

So, first you create an empty string column called `hashtag`. Then, in every loop through the rows, you first extract any number of unique hashtags that might exist in the text into the new column. If none exist, you end up with an empty string (you can change that if you like to something else). And then, you replace the hashtag with an empty space, as you were already doing before.

If it happens that in some texts you have more than 1 hashtag, depending on how you want to use the hashtags later, it could be easier to actually store them as a list, instead of `" ".join(...)`. So, if you want to store them as a list, you could replace row 3 with:

```
df['hashtag'][i] = re.findall("(#[A-Za-z0-9]+)", df['text'][i])
```

which just returns a list of hashtags.

Comment: I tried it with the list, since thats what I want. I get an error though: NameError: name 't' is not defined

Comment: You're right, it was a copying error, as I called `t` my sample text when testing :) Edited!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['hashtags'] = df['text'].str.lower().str.findall(r"(\#[A-z0-9]+)").str.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this string method of pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
pattern = r"(\#[A-z0-9]+)"
df['text'].str.extract(pattern, expand=True)
```

If your string contains multiple matches, you should use `str.extractall`:

```
df['text'].str.extractall(pattern)
```

Comment: does this work with multiple hashtags in one string? as someone else pointed out i'd need a column that stores the hashtags in a list. also how do I apply this as a loop which saves those in a new column 'hashtags'?

Comment: Yes, the `extractall` method would work – but you'd need to do some data manipulation to structure it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I added a couple of lines below your code, it should work:

```
df['hashtags']=''    
for i in range(df.shape[0]) :
    df['text'][i] = ' '.join(re.sub("(#[A-Za-z0-9]+)", " ", df['text'][i]).split()).lower()
    l=df['text'][i].split(0)
    s=[k for k in l if k[0]=='#']
    if len(s)>=1:       
        df['hashtags'][i]=' '.join(s)
```

Comment: I get an error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (At the last row at the 'join')

Comment: Sorry, i fixed it

Comment: Now I got a new error at your row 4 : TypeError: must be str or None, not int

Answer (score 0):

Use `newdf = pd.DataFrame(df.row.str.split('#',1).tolist(),columns = ['text','hashtags'])` instead of you for-loop. This will create a new Dataframe. Then you can set `df['text']=newdf['text']` and `df['hashtags']=newdf['hashtags']`.